# How to programatically add KML Icons to Placemark generated from SimpleFeatures using GeoTools?

Tags: kml, geotools

I have successfully generated a set of (unstyled) placemarks in a KML file using the [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) framework, and the Encoder class. The file renders fine in Google Earth with standard balloon placemarks.

I now want to add some iconstyles to my file. Can anyone give me some guidance here? What is the best way to programatically declare the icons/iconstyles and give each placemark a reference to the corresponding icons? I know the KML syntax for this, but how do I declare/generate this with GeoTools, and make the Encoder class do the final job?